# Delete a menu item in mobile mode in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

have a good time.
I want to delete or hide a menu item from my WordPress site in mobile mode.

- But the code I put in the style file does not work,

menu item code on inspect element mode!

```
<li id="jet-menu-item-2469" class="jet-menu-item jet-menu-item-type-custom jet-menu-item-object-custom jet-menu-item-has-children jet-has-roll-up jet-mega-menu-item jet-mega-menu-position-relative-item jet-regular-item jet-menu-item-has-children jet-menu-item-2469 jet-responsive-menu-item jet-sub-menu-item" style="">
<a class="sub-level-link"><div class="jet-menu-item-wrapper"><div class="jet-menu-title">Tools</div>
<i class="jet-dropdown-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></div></a></li>
```

My code in the style.css file :

```
.select-menu jet-menu-item-2469{
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;}
```

Comment: fix the CSS selector to: .select-menu .jet-menu-item-2469
There is missing dot in front of "jet-menu-item-2469"

Answer (score 1):

There is **#** missing before selector which was not letting the CSS to work.

```
.select-menu #jet-menu-item-2469{
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;}
```